# Eggs battle. This is known problem but I couldn't find solution.

Tags: probability

Two people play this game. There is a bucket with a lot of chicken eggs. Each player pull one, then they knock them (one against other). 
If egg in your hand broken then you lose and other player won.

Question: what is the probability of winning in (n + 1) round.
Answer:  1 – 1/(n+2). But I want o know solution.

p.s. sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an egg has $1\over2$ probability of being broken then each round either player has winning chance $1\over4$ and draw chance $1\over2$

Hence the probability of drawing for all $n+1$ round is $({1\over2})^{n+1}$ and the probability of either player win in $(n+1)$ round is $1-({1\over2})^{n+1}$.

Since each player has equal chance of winning the probability that you win in $(n+1)$ round is ${1\over2}-({1\over2})^{n+2}$. I don't think the answer is correct. The probability you win cannot be larger than $0.5$ in a fair game like this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

I think either I didn't explain conditions good enough or you misunderstood it.
I will try to specify rules again:
- Draw is impossible in this game.
- If you win current round you save your egg for the next and so on until it breaks.
- Egg saves its strength through all the game.

I'm still really interested about solution.